# Filter rows that are increasing by a given step on a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following fields in my table, which keeps track of the items bought by customers :

```
customer_id, item_id, week_id
```

and I would like to filter this table to keep only the customers having bought at least 1 item per week, during at least 5 consecutive weeks.

My current idea is to use a DISTINCT on the customer_id and week_id fields, and then, to do a GROUP BY on the customer_id. However, I do not know which aggregate function I should use, or if I should use an UDF function to do it (so my aggregate function would then be to group the week_id into a set, then apply my UDF on this set).

Another approach would be to create a week_id_1, week_id_2, week_id_3, week_id_4 columns, that I would fill with increased value based on the week_id column, and then, do 5 times a LEFT JOIN on the table on itself (on week_id, then on week_id_1, then on week_id_2, etc.). This seems however quite costy, and I am wondering if there is no better way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am not very familiar with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want five consecutive weeks, then use `join`, assuming that `week_id` increments by 1 for each week.  Here is one way:

```
select distinct customer_id
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id and
        t2.week_id = t1.week_id + 1 join
     t t3
     on t3.customer_id = t1.customer_id and
        t3.week_id = t1.week_id + 2 join
     t t4
     on t4.customer_id = t1.customer_id and
        t4.week_id = t1.week_id + 3 join
     t t5
     on t5.customer_id = t1.customer_id and
        t5.week_id = t1.week_id + 4;
```

Comment: Ok, this is the same approach than my second approach, a bit cleaner as you do not create the columns week_id_1, week_id_2, week_id_3, week_id_4, but use the join to do so.
However, this means that I need 4 joins, which is a quite costy operation if I am not mistaken. Is it the standard way of solving that kind of problems (i.e. joining the table on itself to analyze the dependencies between several rows), or is there a more efficient way to do so, without that many joins?

Comment: Because lets say that I do not want the 5 following weeks, but the 20 following weeks. That would means 19 joins, which would be quite costly.

Comment: @KestemontMax . . . 20 weeks is a different question from 5 weeks.